# Python - Apply rolling median based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the median value for results gathered on several work sessions.

My data looks like that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Session" : [1 ,1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Value" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

I would like to calculate the median for all values in rolling sessions numbers. 
Like the median of all values for sessions 1 and 2, then sessions 2 and 3 ...

Right now the only thing I managed to do is calculate the mean of the medians by doing this :

```
summary = pd.DataFrame()
summary['median_session'] = df.groupby('Session').Value.median()
summary['mean_last_two_median'] = summary.mean_session.rolling(2).mean()
```

But this is not exactly right.

I tried :

```
summary = pd.DataFrame()
summary['mean_two_session'] = df.groupby('Session').rolling(2).median()
```

but I am not getting what I need...

Could someone help me with that? 
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a fully vectorized way, so I would iterate on unique session numbers to build a new DataFrame:

```
resul = pd.DataFrame([[sess, sess+1, df.loc[df['Session'].between(sess, sess+1),
                                            'Value'].median()]
                      for sess in df['Session'].unique()[:-1]],
                     columns=['Session1', 'Session2', 'Median'])
```

It gives:

```
   Session1  Session2  Median
0         1         2     2.5
1         2         3     4.5
```